# Delete functionality is not working in Jqgrid using concrete cms

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, concrete5

I am working in the Concrete5 cms,  i dont know what is wrong in this code,

View page script

```
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($sl) ?>;

    $("#statGrid").jqGrid({
        caption: 'Status List',
        datatype:'local',
        data: myData,
        mtype:'POST',
        colNames:['sID','Status Name','Type','Description'],
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'status_id',editable:true }, 
            {name:'status_name',editable:true },
            {name:'status_type',editable:true },
            {name:'status_description', editable:true, edittype: 'textarea' } ],
        width: "777",
        height: "auto",
        pager:'#statPager',
        rowNum:5, 
        rowList:[5,10,20,30],
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        recreateForm:true,
        gridView: true,
        autoencode: true,
        loadui:'enable'

    }).navGrid("#statPager",{add:false, edit:false, view:false, del:true, search:false, refresh:false },
    {
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    jqModal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    url: "deleteStatus",
    afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
        if (response.responseText == "Success") {
            jQuery("#success").show();
            return [true, response.responseText];
        } else {
                    return [false, response.responseText];
            }
        }
    });
```

Please any1 help how to call my controller function in the url of "deleteStatus" function.

And one more thing is "closeOnEscape: true is not working"

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have putted delete params to wrong position.

jQuery("#grid_id").navGrid('#gridpager',{parameters},prmEdit, prmAdd, **prmDel**, prmSearch, prmView);

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

So, in your case try:

```
.navGrid("#statPager",{add:false, edit:false, del:true, search:false, refresh:false },
        {},{},
        {
        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
        jqModal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        url: "deleteStatus",
        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
            if (response.responseText == "Success") {
                jQuery("#success").show();
                return [true, response.responseText];
            } else {
                        return [false, response.responseText];
                }
            }
        }
,{},{});
```